# ls -lR * lists all the files in current and subdirectories , but ls -lR *filename* does not list files in subdirectories

Tags: unix, ls

ls -lR * lists all the files in current and subdirectories , but ls -lR *filename* does not list files in subdirectories and only lists the files matching *filename* in current directory why so ? is there a way to list all the files whose name contains a particular text without using find and only using ls .

Comment: Which shell are you using? `bash` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the man page ls lists information about the filenames specified. The shell (bash, sh, zsh etc) expands the * to a list of filenames, so the command being execute is

```
ls -lR filename1 filename2 filename3 ...
```

If one of those filenames is a directory then ls will list it recursively.

In your second case

```
ls -lR filename
```

If that filename is the name of a directory, ls will list the contents of the directory recusively, otherwise it will give you details of the file.

To do what you want you will need to do

```
ls -lR | grep filename
```

Or use find as you say